# Read Specfic text from a file and Fill up boxex in excel

Tags: excel, vba

/                         Shunt IDENTITIES FILES
/                         -----------------------

/Main Shunts
/------------

```
    S101            S103            S105            S106            S107 
    S108            S112            S113            S115            S116 
    S117            S118            S119            S120            S122  
    S123            S505            S507            S509            S510 
    S511            S512
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Hi I want to code the above in VBA so that only text like "S###" is being read and copied in excel column. So I have managed to code below however its coping anything that starts with S.

Thanks for the help

```
        Open selectedPaths(I) For Input As #1
        Close #1

      x = 4
        Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, txt

        Lines = Split(txt, " ")

        For Each Line In Lines

        If Line Like "S*" Then

            If x Mod 30 = 0 Then
                x = x + 4
            End If
                Cells(x, 1) = Line
            x = x + 1
            Cells(x, 1) = Line

            If x Mod 30 <> 0 Then
                x = x + 1
            End If

        End If
        Next
        Loop

       Close #1

    Next I
End If
```

Comment: Your question is not clear ... what sort of text you want to copy? Anything that starts with S and have 4 chars?

Comment: Anything that starts with S and followed by digits i.e S103, S1051

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 If Line Like "S*" Then
```

with

```
If Line Like "S????" Then
```

Comment: This works perfect apart from it picks up "SDS1" too which I dont want

Comment: Anything that could limit it to the format "Snnn" where n is a digit  THANKS

Comment: If Line like "S###" Then

Comment: Just wondering if there would be way in regular expressions to do it .

Comment: You can use something like `S[0-9]+`